# Change data in a file

Tags: xml, linux, shell

I'm looking for a way to change some data in many files (change xml encoding). There are a lot of files (more than 1 000 000). What is the fastest way ? Sed, grep, something else ? Thank's!

Change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sed for this.  If that's the only place "ASCII" shows up it would be easy to do

```
sed -i -e 's/ASCII/UTF-8/' <file>
```

Note: the `-i` flag without argument is GNU syntax.  Also, if  ASCII appears anywhere that you do not want to replace you'll have to make your pattern more specific.

This is going to create a new `sed` process for each file.  So performance-wise, you might be better served trying to write a script that will open the files and make the changes without having to launch new processes.  In python you could write a function to do it and use `os.walk` to navigate a directory structure finding the files you want.

Comment: Can also specify only the first line : `sed -i -e '1s/ASCII/UTF-8/' <file>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact match and replace, then:

```
sed -i -Ee 's/(<?xml version="1.0" encoding=")ASCII/\1UTF-8/' file
```

You can account for multiple spaces or tabs in tag line like this:

```
sed -i -Ee 's/(<?xml[ \t]+version="1.0"[ \t]+encoding=")ASCII/\1UTF-8/' file
```

I only considered spaces in `xml version="1.0"` and `version="1.0" encoding=...` where I made at least one white space compulsory...